# Simple Math Game in JavaScript&HTML , Gets error from if/else

Tags: javascript, html

I don't understand why the "*alert*" from the *if/else* conditioning always gets me an error - while its defenetly not!

I tried to change it to "*switch*" , get the variables inside and out the function , but none of this helped.

```
const randomNumb = {
  x: Math.round((Math.random()) * 10 + 1),
  y: Math.round((Math.random()) * 10 + 1)
};

const action1 = document.querySelector("#theAction");
const firstNum = document.querySelectorAll("#numbers")[0];
const secondNum = document.querySelectorAll("#numbers")[1];
firstNum.innerHTML = randomNumb.x;
secondNum.innerHTML = randomNumb.y;

if (firstNum > secondNum) {
  action1.innerHTML = "-";
} else {
  action1.innerHTML = "+";
}

const answer1 = randomNumb.x - randomNumb.y;
const answer2 = randomNumb.x + randomNumb.y;

const checkButton = document.querySelector("input[type=button][value=Check]");
const checkAnswer = document.querySelector("input[type=text]");
const theValue = checkAnswer.value;


checkButton.onclick = function() {

  if (theValue === answer1 || theValue === answer2){
    alert("Correct!")
  } else {
    alert("Error")
  }

  location.reload();
};
```

I'm trying to do that when I'm putting the correct answer in the "**checkAnswer**" it will put correct. if not , Error.
but it keeps giving me "**Error**" all the time.
Any suggestions ? (maybe I could write the code better in general?)

Comment: `id`s are always unique in page. But it seems you have same id `numbers` for two elements

Comment: What's the exact error, and could you post your HTML?

Comment: _but it keeps giving me "Error"_. What is that error. Can you please create a snippet

Comment: The "Error" I meant is the alert("Error") Everything is flowing , (I think so)

Answer (score 0):

To verify to yourself [check this link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_typeof_all) and check what type of an object you are trying to compare in your if/else statement.

```
const action1 = document.querySelector("#theAction");
const firstNum = document.querySelectorAll("#numbers")[0]; // this is a HTML element
const secondNum = document.querySelectorAll("#numbers")[1];
firstNum.innerHTML = randomNumb.x;
secondNum.innerHTML = randomNumb.y;

if (firstNum > secondNum) { // comparision is not possible
  action1.innerHTML = "-";
 } else {
 action1.innerHTML = "+";
}
```

Let's access the value inside the HTML element and cast it to Number() for example

```
if (Number(firstNum.innerHTML) > Number(secondNum)) { // comparision is possible
  action1.innerHTML = "-";
 } else {
 action1.innerHTML = "+";
}
```

this will solve the issue you are currently having, cheers!

Comment: also , my problem was here:  ** if (theValue === answer1 || theValue === answer2)...**  It kept giving me alert("Error")

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

```
checkButton.onclick = function() {
const theValue = checkAnswer.value;
  if (theValue === answer1){
    alert("correct")
  } else if (theValue == answer2){
    alert("correct")
  } else {
    alert("error")
  };

};
```

Comment: Accept the answer yourselves so that others will find the right answer easily